# Orbeon - Found a valid lock file

Tags: orbeon

I'm having an application that access orbeon many times concurrently. I found that sometimes when I stop/start the orbeon WAR this message appears:

**The database directory seems to be locked by another instance. Found valid lock file: /"path"/orbeon.war/WEB-INF/exist-data/dbx_dir.lck**

I stop and start Orbeon and it start working again.

Do you have any idea why this could be happening?

Regards,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a lock file created by the [eXist database](http://exist-db.org/), which comes bundled with Orbeon Forms. The purpose of this lock file it to prevent two instances of eXist from accessing the same data files on disk, as this would eventually lead to data corruption.

The lock file should be removed when you shut down your application server, e.g. Tomcat. But depending on how you do it, eXist may not have a chance to remove its lock file, and hence will complain the next time you start it.

However, there is nothing there you should worry about. If you are sure you never have another instance of eXist accessing the same files, you can even remove that lock file as part of the script you use to start Tomcat.

Comment: Hi thanks! with this I was able to find an other post of a similar problem (http://orbeon-forms-ops-users.24843.n4.nabble.com/Problem-in-a-non-persistant-session-environment-td3069014.html) 
I'm using websphere with orbeon 3.7. Seems that is a known bug. What about using Orbeon 3.9 it is backward compatible with old xforms?

Comment: It is mostly compatible, you but might still have to change a few things here and there when upgrading. Incompatibilities are mentioned in the *compatibility notes* for each release. If you're coming from 3.7, you'll want to check the 3.8 release notes (http://wiki.orbeon.com/forms/doc/developer-guide/release-notes/38) and 3.9 release notes (http://wiki.orbeon.com/forms/doc/developer-guide/release-notes/39).

Comment: Well the problem persist even when we are not in maintenance hours, so it seems may be a problem with a middle proxy or something. I don't really know why the .lck file was there preventing from entering all users after some time. Do you have a tip on this?

Comment: Hi
 About journal.lck and dbx_dir.lck. 
 Those file are constantly being modified even if I not access orbeon form. Do you know why are being modified constantly and what is being written all the time? What information is preventing to access twice? since they are read only form. I'm thinking on adding a cron job to erase de file constantly but need to understand fully why is happening this.

Many thanks for your help on this topic.

Comment: I don't think anything interesting if written to those files. They are just lock files that indicate that an application is currently using the database files, thus preventing another app from attempting to write to the same database files.

Answer (score 0):

Stopping the exist service resolved this for me.